# Angular 2 Cors error when adding headers to Http.get

Tags: angularjs, typescript, soapui

When I call **Soap ui service** without headers its working and server returns json:

```
return this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.json());
```

but when I add header:

```
var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.get(url,{headers: headers})
            .map(res => res.json());
```

browser returns cors error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://desktop-0n2fu3g:8089/RechercherClients. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

I have already configured my SOAP UI service with headers:
[image]

Is there any solution to make that work?

Comment: I don't think your problem is with angular, but rather with the http headers set by your server. You should look at how you can configure your server to allow for requests from localhost as origin. :)

Comment: Cannot answer as more info would be useful. This might not be the default POST cors headers but instead be the pre-flight request. For this you would also need to add the relevant headers as otherwise the pre-flight will refuse your app permission to talk to the server with the actual request that your above added headers would deal with.